# Looking for old Open Type font

Tags: font-identification, typefaces, opentype

I have to recreate this logo, and I have exhausted my considerable font finding resources. Judging by the OTF swashes and accents, the design looks very 80's / 90's or so to me.  Possibly even 70's.

It's really bugging me because that curly on the S at the end looks familiar.  I just can NOT find it, and I have a few weeks to get this done, so I thought I'd post up here and see if anyone recognizes it before I go through the fun of a manual clean up.

This scan is from a fiber stock thermography business card, so I'm guessing the original logo is much more crisp, with sharp corners rather than rounded, but that's just a guess.  There's also a good chance that the original font had a stroke added to give it an artificial black letter look.

[image: Unique Productions]

Here are a few letters that I already isolated for searching if it helps.

[image: Isolated Letters]

Here's a better scan:

[image: UP Logo]

Comment: It is feasible that some of those swashes are custom and created around a base font. As Copilot points out, it could be modified Bookman.

Comment: the serifs on the rest of the letters don't match up with Bookman.  I tried looking for that too (a font for the regular letters to add the swashes to) and didn't find anything.  The serifs (or lack there of) on the E, S, W and C don't match up. And the stroke variations aren't right either.

Comment: It could be entirely custom drawn. After all it appears to be a logo.

Comment: This is very true.  But you don't know if you don't ask.  It's very uniform, so I think it started from at least a base font.

Comment: That E is the key.  I KNOW i've seen a font with that type of serifs, I just can't remember / find it.

Comment: At least the smaller text is reasonably easy: with the narrow W and asymmetric D you'll get away with Palatino (the S isn't right for that, but it's one letter and small).

Comment: Palatino is way too thin, and has way wrong serifs on almost all the letters.

Comment: So far this is the closest I've found, but it's about a year old, so it's not it.  https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hoftype/tangent/black/

Comment: "old Open Type" is somewhat of an oxymoron. If it's old, it won't be in the Open Type format.

Comment: true to a point.  I have OT fonts going back to the late 90's.  I have no clue how old this logo is, so everything is only guessing based on style.

Comment: It might be a modified [Cooper Black](https://www.myfonts.com/search/name%3Acooper/fonts/). The original was released in 1922, so there are hundreds of (slight) modifications and alternate versions.

Comment: The inward pointing wedge serif on the S is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest I've found, and I'm conceding defeat. ah well.
thank you for all the help!

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hoftype/tangent/black/

Answer (score 0):

From the serifs it could be Bookman, which cold type designers loved giving insane swashes. But this beats most of the ones I've seen.

Comment: Not bad, but look at the "E", the center bar has a unique slant on the end.  Bookman has full serifs on the center bar.

Comment: Yes, that is a major difference. I tried searching for that on Identifont, selecting "don't know" or normal later shapes for other characters, but didn't find any other families that seem to have been issued with a large swash range.

Comment: I've tried identifont, What The Font, whatfontis, and a bunch of weird ones.  I also to Graphictracer that has a font recognition feature.  Usually at least ONE of my resources gets me close, but i'm coming up empty here.

Comment: It reminded me immediately of Cooper Black, but there are differences. In Cooper, the counter on O is tilted, and the middle bar on the E has a distinct serif. But the feel is very similar. I wonder if this wasn't originally a letraset type that was modified.

Comment: The 'E' with no center serif could be influenced by Palatino. Yet the overall structure suggests Bookman as a starting point.